# Microsoft´s sqlsrv driver for PHP not returning any result when querying "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id"

Tags: php, sql-server

this query works fine using the php_mssql driver:

```
INSERT INTO Table(columnName) VALUES ('text');
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id;
```

Table does have an id column, which is an identity.
I would execute that query, and get the last id in the table.

The same code doesn´t work if the query is executed using Microsoft´s php_sqlsrv driver.

I don´t get any error when executing the query (sqlsrv_query function) , but i get the following error when calling sqlsrv_fetch_array:
"The active result for the query contains no fields"

I´ve googled a lot, and didn´t find no answer, it was a big surprise for me that no one faced this problem before, it seems like nobody is using this driver, even though is the "official" one since PHP 5.3 release...

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the initial CTP the field indices started at 1. Later they were changed to start at 0.

Try something like this:

```
// connection to the dbserver

$result = sqlsrv_query("INSERT INTO Table(columnName) VALUES ('text'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID");

echo "The last insert_id is".lastId($result);

function lastId($queryID) {
     sqlsrv_next_result($queryID);
     sqlsrv_fetch($queryID);
     return sqlsrv_get_field($queryID, 0);
}
```

Comment: This code gave me the clue to find out what´s happening. INSERT_QUERY returns 1 result, and SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY returns another result. If you are pointing towards the 1st result you get an error if you try to fetch an array (the insert query doesn´t return anything), so you have to make the next result available (sqlsrv_next_result) and then you can call sqlsrv_fetch_array. WATCH OUT if you are migrating from php_mssql to php_sqlsrv, because this behaviour is different, and can possibly lead to errors.

Comment: I had similar issue; i used sqlsrv_next_result($result) to resolve it. At first it didn't solve the issue; then later on I found that there was a PRINT() statement in my SP which caused the problem. I had to remove PRINT() and use sqlsrv_next_result($result) also to solve it. don't we have anything that would let sqlsrv_query() discard PRINT()???

Comment: I had the same issue with the "Messages" data generated by SQL Server.  Using sqlsrv_next_result() resolved it.