# PHP, MSSQL, SQLSRV (prepared) driver; How do I get the ID of the row I've just inserted?

Tags: php, sql-server, prepared-statement

**I'm looking to produce the last inserted id using SQLSRV.  I need to use a prepared statement though.**  I've seen an answer on here (see link after the code below) showing how to do it, but the statement isn't prepared for anti-sql injection purposes.

```
//Prep the variables for insert
$p1 = $_POST['description'];
$p2 = intval($_POST['visible']);
$p3 = strval($_POST['whoToShow']);

//Build an array with those variables
$params = array(&$p1, &$p2, &$p3);

//Build the SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO notifications (description, visible, whoToShow) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

//Execute the sql using a prepared statement, passing the variables in an array
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params) or die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));
```

Please review [Microsoft´s sqlsrv driver for PHP not returning any result when querying "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336473/microsofts-sqlsrv-driver-for-php-not-returning-any-result-when-querying-select) on Stack Overflow for details on getting the last inserted ID using a non prepared statement.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a stored procedure instead of a direct INSERT statement.  Using a stored procedure is better as you can return a recordset from the stored procedure which would include the ID of the inserted record.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server with my PHP.  I am using the mssql_query library to connect to SQL server.
Not sure if it makes a difference, but I see you're using a different library to connect.  Every query we do is through stored procedures.  Its far more efficient and definitely more secure.

```
$myServer = "xxxxxxx";
$myUser = "xxxxxxxx";
$myPass = "xxxxxxx";
$myDB = "myDatabase";
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");

$query = "exec eCommerce.dbo.cart_GET_Detail    @sid = ".$_SESSION['sid']." , @cc = '".$_SESSION['cc']."'";

$result = mssql_query($query);
$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result);
$hasItems = (($numRows == 0) ? 'N' : 'Y');

while ($RSLoop = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
    //var_dump($RSLoop);  //var_dump will show you everything in the recordset
    echo '<tr><td colspan=6 width=720 class=cartDivider>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
    echo '<form name=frmProduct'.$idx.' method=POST action=_action.asp>';
    echo '<input type=hidden name=pid value="'.$RSLoop['product_id'].'">';
}
```

That was a call to a stored procedure to get the contents of the shopping cart stored in a SQL table.
Doing an insert on a stored procedure is similar.  You should be able to find some code samples on SQL Server stored procedures.

Comment: Do you have a stored procedure that you're currently using that I could take a look at?  It would be nice to see how it is integrated in a php script as well.

Comment: I added some code to call a stored procedure.  For an example of writing your own stored procedure take a look at this page: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic749136-9-1.aspx