# Unable to connect sqlsrv php call stored procedure

Tags: php, sqlsrv

i took below SP HIt using sqlsrv and PHP.  Snippet does not worked for me. For the below code i am getting " SQL SRV QUERY NOT RAN ". please provide your advise, how to achieve php + sqlsrv + SP.

```
$query = "{CALL call_user_name}";

if ( ($res = sqlsrv_query( CONNSTR, $query)) )
{
   do 
   {
      if ( sqlsrv_num_fields($res) ) // one way to check if results returned.

      {
         while( ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $res, $type)) )
         {
            $data[] = $row; 
         }
      }else{echo "sqlsrv_num_fields not working";}
   } while ( sqlsrv_next_result($res) ) ;
   sqlsrv_free_stmt($res); // not essential, but good form if your script does lots of other stuff.
}else{
       echo "SQL SRV QUERY NOT RAN ";die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: perhaps you don't need to `$params` in your `sqlsrv_query` when it is empty.

Comment: what does `CONNSTR` mean? do you mean `$CONNSTR`? if it is a typo, please put your connection string code.

Comment: Db connection string.

Comment: Please put your connection string codes

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible causes for your error, my suggestion: change this line

> echo "SQL SRV QUERY NOT RAN"

to

> die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

Then you can see what is causing the error.

Comment: Getting SQL SRV QUERY NOT RAN Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server] RYBACK [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]RYBACK ) ) 

but sqlsrv_query get failed, getting above array in the die(print_r())

Comment: Getting Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -28 [code] => -28 [2] => The active result for the query contains no fields. [message] => The active result for the query contains no fields. ) )

Comment: maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336473/microsofts-sqlsrv-driver-for-php-not-returning-any-result-when-querying-select

Answer (score 0):

Sample PHP SQL Srv stored Procedure call (With parameters). Hope this will help you to get an idea. (Used to call this php file through Ajax request and Return data after calling the SP)

**smeSelectDrp is the SP Name**

```
$sql = "EXEC smeSelectDrp";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
echo "Error Retrieving Data";
die;
}
else 
{
while($row  = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC) ) {
$value[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($value);
}
```